# How to automatically create test data with builder that will take verifications into account

Tags: c#, unit-testing, verification, test-data, nbuilder

I am using [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) to create test data and my classes have a large number of properties so manual creation is out of question. Before I used NBuilder I copy pasted some SQL selects to csv files and recreated them in tests using automatic mapping. Now I want to use NBuilder or something else and I face the problem of Entity/DB restrictions.

Is there any way I can tell some of those builders to take into account my Mapping file when generating data. For instance, if there is a mapping

```
  this.Property(t => t.SomeId)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(3);
```

I would expect the framework to generate test data for that property according to those requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could use [Linq-to-EDMX](http://linqtoedmx.codeplex.com/) to access the mapping information for your entities.  Having that information you could use NBuilder's `CreateNew` method do something like this:

```
// Linq-to-EDMX was used to get the propertyLength value
x => x.SomeId = randomString.Substring(0, propertyLength)
```